# Javascript Function object call() in NODEJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have read through call() method and wondering on the global output below. Shouldnt it be this.name where in this case "Michael". However the output displayed is undefined.

---NEW INFORMATION : THIS IS RUNNING THROUGH NODEJS---

```
function sayNameForAll(label) {
console.log(label + ":" + this.name);
 }

var person1 = {
name: "Nicholas"
};

var person2 = {
name: "Greg"
};

var name = "Michael";

sayNameForAll.call(this,"global");  //ouput global:undefined
sayNameForAll.call(person1,"PersonName1"); //PersonName1:Nicholas
sayNameForAll.call(person2,"PersonName2"); //PersonName2:Greg
```

Comment: How do you call this code? Are you sure you're in a global scope? It works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/7pxsh8gh/

Comment: your code works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is probably that in this context, `this` is not the same scope. This can happen because of several reasons:

- You're running this in a function (even a `(function() { self invoking function })()`)
- You're running this in nodejs and not in the browser, in node, in the global scope, `this` is `undefined` as opposed to `window` in the browser.

Comment: @zerkms Because in the global scope in node, `this` is `undefined` as opposed to `window` in the browser.

Comment: oh yes i am running on nodejs...How could this explain

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here (click Run Snippet).

Is your code running inside another function? If it is, then the variables you declare would not be on the global object and depending on how you are invoking the function, `this` might not refer to the global object.

```js
function sayNameForAll(label) {
    console.log(label + ":" + this.name);
}

var person1 = {
    name: "Nicholas"
};

var person2 = {
    name: "Greg"
};

var name = "Michael";

sayNameForAll.call(this,"global");  //ouput global:undefined
sayNameForAll.call(person1,"PersonName1"); //PersonName1:Nicholas
sayNameForAll.call(person2,"PersonName2"); //PersonName2:Greg
```

Comment: Because in the global scope in node, this is undefined as opposed to window in the browser. –  Second Rikudo